# Необходимо спарсить цену с карточки товара при выбранном городе Самара. Проблема с куки

Tags: python, парсер, cookie

У меня задание спарсить цену с карточки товара. Сложность в том, что при отработке кода выводит цену по городу Москва, а надо, чтобы выводил по городу Самаре. Поменял город на сайте, всё равно выводит Москва. Затем я из API заголовка скопировал куки, передал ему вид словаря и вставил в запрос. Результат- снова цена по Москве. Вопрос: как из карточки товара (ссылку прикреплю ниже) спарсить цену при выбранном городе Самара? Может я неправильно скопировал куки?

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla / 5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) '
                    'AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 108.0.0.0 Safari / 537.36',
    'accept': '*/*',
}

cookies = {
    'yandexuid': '3887315071669469872',
    'yuidss': '3887315071669469872',
    'yabs-sid': '846735381669469872',
    'ymex': '1984829872.yrts.16694698721984829872.yrtsi.1669469872',
    'yp': '1685242399.szm.1:1366x768:1366x657',
    'my': 'YwA=',
    'is_gdpr': '0',
    'is_gdpr_b': 'CIy8DhDRlwEoAg==',
    'gdpr': '0',
    '_ym_uid': '1671480159614150081',
    '_ym_d': '1671480164',
    'i': 'sFL4FsvlMdo8Gu835Ux5/wSCkCHiDDL+vPpFHQfTfKd1frzRkba0cEr4imgsc5s9W95d2tWA6L4inAqXb3y0ntZw2Eo=',
    'yashr': '1890506521674058975',
}

url = 'https://torex.ru/catalog/product/1989484/'
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {'CITY': '%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0'}

response = requests.get('https://torex.ru/catalog/product/1989484/', cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span', class_="underline_dashed").text)

# Самара
```

Comment: Работает, благодарю! Был бы благодарен за объяснение как получить куки. Вроде бы я делал всё правильно.

Comment: Браузер-инструменты веб разработчика-сеть-куки-куки запросов